# Opening fragment from RecyclerViewAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I need to open a new fragment when the user clicks on a recyclerview item.

I am using following code:

```
@Override
public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
    switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_favourite:




            mPref = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);


            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPref.edit();
            Log.d("HOLA PERFIL", "HE PULSADO EL PRODUCTO: " + tiendas.get(pos).getId_producto());


            editor.putInt("ID_PRODUCTO", tiendas.get(pos).getId_producto());
            editor.putString("NOMBRE_PRODUCTO", tiendas.get(pos).getNombre_producto());
            editor.putString("DESCRIPCION_PRODUCTO", tiendas.get(pos).getDescripcion_producto());
            editor.putString("PRESENTACION_PRODUCTO", tiendas.get(pos).getPresentacion_producto());
            editor.putString("PRECIO_PRODUCTO", tiendas.get(pos).getPrecio_producto());
            editor.putString("ESPECIFICACIONES_PRODUCTO", tiendas.get(pos).getEspecificaciones_producto());
            editor.putString("IMAGEN_PRODUCTO", tiendas.get(pos).getImagen_producto());
            editor.apply();


            DetalleTiendaFragment firstFragment = new DetalleTiendaFragment();
            ((MainActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.frame, firstFragment);




            return true;

        default:
    }
    return false;
}
```

I am using the same action on other projects and it works fine, but here it doesn´t open the fragment, and no warning or error is thrown:

```
DetalleTiendaFragment firstFragment = new DetalleTiendaFragment();
                    ((MainActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                            .add(R.id.frame, firstFragment);
```

Comment: beginTransaction()....commit();

Comment: @matoni, what do you mean?

Comment: I think, the reason why fragment is not displayed is that you forget to call commit();. Standard flow is: getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(...).commit();

Comment: @mvasco see my answer I hope it helps. Feel free to ask me if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this code

```
DetalleTiendaFragment firstFragment = new DetalleTiendaFragment();
            ((MainActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.frame, firstFragment);
```

To this code

```
DetalleTiendaFragment firstFragment = new DetalleTiendaFragment();   
FragmentTransaction transaction = ((MainActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.frame, firstFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack("firstFragment");
transaction.commit();
```

Comment: No problem. :) Happy to help you.